# "requires external JavaScript from another domain" error with googleapis ENABLED

Tags: support, dns

I am currently getting a red banner reading: "... requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load." on StackExchange sites.

I used to get a similar banner about jQuery if I had googleapis.com blocked, but I *do not* have it blocked now.  Furthermore, the sites appear to be working fine apart from this banner.

Should I just ignore it?

Correction: the sites *were* working correctly, but now different features seem to be broken, such as live message preview, and the notification fly-out next to Stack**Exchange**.

Also, the button in the edit view are now gone.  What's changed?

Apparently I cannot post comments now either.

---

I cannot post comments, so I will have to append them to this message instead.

I am using Firefox 4.0.1.  Everything was working just fine until now.  I did not change my configuration.

---

If I paste `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js` into the URL bar, I get the error:

> Firefox can't find the server at ajax.googleapis.com.

Is this to be expected, or an indication of what is going wrong?  Again, I haven't changed any settings and everything was working fine.

I tried `ipconfig /flushdns` but it did not help.

Comment: I have started seeing this error message but only when I use Safari on my iPhone. I have cleared my cache & cookies and now I cannot log in.

Comment: @Barry I am sorry to hear that.  I was hoping this was a one time glitch in Firefox.  For some reason a reboot fixed it, at least for the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved, I hope.

I did a full reboot, and now this site is working again.  I have no idea why that helped.

Before rebooting, I tried `ipconfig /flushdns` without effect.

Comment: this happened in my mac FF, i restarted FF and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a browser configuration issue.

Can you try

- disabling all browser extensions or working in "browser safe mode"
- a different web browser than you normally use with a default install

and see if that helps?

Comment: Jeff, I did not change anything in my browser config or extensions.  A reboot fixed the problem.  I would love to know why.

Comment: I had the same problem after (and thirst thought because) updating Firefox to version 10, but then I tried Opera, and had the same problem there.

Answer (score 0):

> Firefox can't find the server at ajax.googleapis.com.

No, that's not to be expected. This is a configuration or networking issue on your side – I can reach ajax.googleapis.com fine from here, and there has been *no change at all* regarding the address we pull jQuery from.

The last change was on April 30, and this only switched from jQuery 1.5.1 to 1.5.2.

Comment: Do you know why a reboot would fix my problem, while `/flushdns` did nothing?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I think Firefox has its own internal DNS cache, which would be unaffected by flushdns; maybe that was it.