# Error with Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“requires external JavaScript from another domain” error with googleapis ENABLED](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90460/requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain-error-with-googleapis-enabled)

Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.

The above error I encountered while using Stack Overflow on Google Chrome. What's this error? how to fix it?

Also I am sure that my browser allows JavaScripts from all sites.

Comment: @Bojan K - Yeah.! I forgot.! Am sorry to ask this here. Next time I will follow.

Comment: Please read [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90460/requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain-error-with-googleapis-enabled)

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

May be its asking Jquery from Google !

Comment: Okay.! But what to do from my side to make Stack Overflow work fine on my browser?